# One bus or separate buses in CQRS?

Tags: architecture, cqrs, servicebus

I was wondering if I should have one bus where I register my commands/events and comand handlers/event handlers or as my application now has a number of bounded contexts, should I have separate buses?

What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 3):

Buses should primarily be considered an infrastructure concern, not a domain concern. How will you be deploying your application?

Comment: Slightly confused here. As this is my first CQRS project, I followed Greg Young's simple CQRS project which had a bus that registered events and commands. I then started reading more about DDD and as I was working in different domains, I created a bus which registered commands for that domain. Then as I worked on other domains, I created another bus and registered the commands for it there. So maybe my understanding of a bus in this context is wrong. It just felt the right thing to do logically at the time. You mentioned deploy, do you mean if I am using NSB etc?

Comment: If you expose a bus abstraction to your domain, you still have the choice to determine at run time the nature of the bus supplied. That is, you could make different choices when deploying two BCs in one process (i.e. an in-memory bus) or on different machines (a service bus). Or inject different busses to different handlers for low- and high-priority messages.

Answer (score 1):

a bus is a transport, if some your contexts have low messages traffic you can use a single bus for them, but for some other contexts you'll need several buses to transport one context messages.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean here?